# How the customize or change the route paths in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example consider the following output from rake routes:-
         ***posts*** GET    /posts(.:format)                      {:action=>"index",   :controller=>"posts"}
                 ***posts POST***   /posts(.:format)                      {:action=>"create",   :controller=>"posts"}
              ***new_post*** GET    /posts/new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new",   :controller=>"posts"}
             ***edit_post*** GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit",   :controller=>"posts"}
                  ***post*** GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"show",   :controller=>"posts"}

If i want to change the path name of "new_post" to "create_post" how do I do it ??

Comment: Which version of Rails are you running?

Answer (score 4):

`match '/posts/new' => 'posts#new', :as => :create_post` in your routes should work!

Answer (score 4):

You must checkout [railscast for routing in rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3)

Btwn solution for your problem

```
 match '/posts/new' => 'posts#new', :as => :create_post
```

Answer (score 3):

A 'match' here is not appropriate. It can pose a security issue because by default it opens up the route you are matching to every request verb (get, post, etc). You should either specify the verb in place of match

```
get '/posts/new' => 'posts#new', as: :create_post
```

or you can specify what verbs you want to use, using match

```
match '/posts/new' => 'posts#new', as: :create_post, via: [:get]
```

Answer (score 1):

In `rails 5` you can do it like -

```
get '/create_post', to: 'posts#new'
```

You should prefer `http method keywords` instead of directly using `match` as per [API docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/match).
Also I would choose default `RESTful` routes generated by `resources` method in Rails instead defining all custom REST routes.